# Squid with SSLbump and authentification 403. It is an encapsulated request do not authenticate

Tags: squid

I have a problem with my squid v3.5.27.

squid.conf

```
acl auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl basicauth           proxy_auth_regex -i service
http_access deny !auth
http_access deny basicauth
http_access allow all

http_port 0.0.0.0:3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/squid/etc/squidCA.pem
ssl_bump bump all
sslproxy_cert_error deny all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /etc/squid/ssl_db -M 10MB
```

Iam authentificated by USERTEST, but get TCP_DENIED/403, when I try to open any sites

access.log:

```
17/May/2018:12:35:18 +0300 10.0.5.177         USERTEST     TCP_DENIED/403 https://rbc.ru "-"
```

cache.log:

```
2018/05/17 12:35:18.484 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x38457c8 checking slow rules
2018/05/17 12:35:18.484 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking http_access
2018/05/17 12:35:18.484 kid1| 28,5| Checklist.cc(400) bannedAction: Action 'DENIED/0' is not banned
2018/05/17 12:35:18.484 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking http_access#1
2018/05/17 12:35:18.484 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking !auth
2018/05/17 12:35:18.484 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking auth
2018/05/17 12:35:18.484 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(36) AuthenticateAcl: SslBumped request: It is an encapsulated request do not authenticate
2018/05/17 12:35:18.484 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: auth = 1
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: !auth = 0
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: http_access#1 = 0
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Checklist.cc(400) bannedAction: Action 'ALLOWED/0' is not banned
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking http_access#2
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking basicauth
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(36) AuthenticateAcl: SslBumped request: It is an encapsulated request do not authenticate
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: basicauth = 1
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking sites1
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| DomainData.cc(108) match: aclMatchDomainList: checking 'www.rbc.ru'
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| DomainData.cc(113) match: aclMatchDomainList: 'www.rbc.ru' NOT found
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: sites1 = 0
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: http_access#2 = 0
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Checklist.cc(400) bannedAction: Action 'DENIED/0' is not banned
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking http_access#3
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(138) matches: checking basicauth
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Acl.cc(36) AuthenticateAcl: SslBumped request: It is an encapsulated request do not authenticate
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: basicauth = 1
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: http_access#3 = 1
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(158) matches: checked: http_access = 1
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x38457c8 answer DENIED for match
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x38457c8 answer=DENIED
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Gadgets.cc(83) aclIsProxyAuth: aclIsProxyAuth: called for basicauth
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,9| Acl.cc(99) FindByName: ACL::FindByName 'basicauth'
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,5| Gadgets.cc(88) aclIsProxyAuth: aclIsProxyAuth: returning 1
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,8| Gadgets.cc(51) aclGetDenyInfoPage: got called for basicauth
2018/05/17 12:35:18.485 kid1| 28,8| Gadgets.cc(70) aclGetDenyInfoPage: aclGetDenyInfoPage: no match
```

As you can see I hit in acl *basicauth = 1* and *http_access#3 = 1* despite the fact that I have a different login. If I disable SSLbump - all works fine.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

For Basic Authentication:

```
 auth_param basic program  /usr/bin/python /home/test/auth.py
 auth_param basic realm Please enter username and password
 auth_param basic children 100
 auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 second
 acl AuthUsers proxy_auth REQUIRED
```

In the above, test.py represents you can write your custom python script for the authentication or you can also use any other method.

and for ssl-bump you can do:

```
 http_port 3128 ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid/ssl/myca.pem generate-host- 
 certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB

 sslcrtd_program /usr/lib/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/spool/squid_ssldb -M 4MB
 sslcrtd_children 5

 acl tcp_level at_step SslBump1
 ssl_bump peek tcp_level all
 ssl_bump bump all
```

and for allowing the access

```
 http_access allow AuthUsers
 http_access deny all
```